# Verify dbms_sql.execute executed code PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, database, bind-variables

Is there a way to track what code has been executed using dbms_sql.execute?

For example if I run this query:

```
DECLARE
    cursor_name INTEGER;
    rows_processed INTEGER;
BEGIN
    cursor_name := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_name, 'SELECT * FROM dual WHERE 2 = :x' ,DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':x', 2);
    rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);   
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
END;
```

I should be able to find the result:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE 2 = 2
```

I've tried looking in v$sql/v$sql_bind_capture and dba_hist_sqltext/dba_hist_sqlbind but it seems unreliable since running the same sql with different bind variables causes the sql with the same sql_id to be overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to capture all bind variables is to perform hard-parse on each execution.
The easy way to achieve this is to purge the cursor from heap after it has been executed as following:

```
-- get sqlAddr and hashVal from v$sqlarea
SYS.dbms_shared_pool.purge(SqlAddr||', '||hashVal,'c',127); -- 127 is a bitmask for heaps 0~7 to be freed
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_shared_pool.htm#CHDCBEBB

After that you can rely on v$sql_bind_capture for mapping bind variables.